How to connect for loop with find option
How can i connect
For loop that goes on all files in folder and find in each string then add this string to a variable
I need list of files in folder + find in that files line that contains "string" and give that line
Exactly what I need is this:
I have a folder and in it various files x.txt y.txt and many others
I need to put a list of these files into csv and find the line containing "string" and next to put the whole line
example:
db.csv 
output x.txt "aaaaaa string aaaaaaa" 
y.txt "asfdsaf string dfsadsa"

FOR %%i IN (folder/*.*) DO (
        set var = find "text"
    echo %%i ; var >> db.csv
)


Not tested:
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%i IN (folder\*.*) DO (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('type "%%~fi" ^| find "string"') do (
        set "var=%%#"
    )
    echo %%i ; !var! >> db.csv
)

you need a delayed expansion and nested for loop to assign a result of a command into a variable

I tried it but all the time get var empty

@MateuszF - right at the moment I have no access to a windows machine. What is the result if you set echo %%i on the line before the inner for loop?

@MateuszF - may be you can use FOR /D -> https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

@MateuszF worked for me when I've changed the slash with backslash (script is also updated)

same data can be extracted with just one command: findstr "text" "folder\*" >"db.csv" (maybe using the /i switch). Then replace the : with a ; with a surrounding for loop
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i "test" "*"') do echo %%a;%%b)>"db.csv"

If not - please be more precise with what you want (an example maybe?).

Exactly what I need is this:
I have a folder and in it various files x.txt y.txt and many others
i need to put a list of these files into csv and find the line containing "string" and next to put the whole line
example:
db.csv output
x.txt "aaaaaa string aaaaaaa"
y.txt "asfdsaf string dfsadsa"

ok, that's what I understood. Does my code work for you? If not - what's the issue?

No its not working, It gave me empty csv
FOR %%i IN (Zliczanie/.) DO (
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i "string" "folder/*"') do echo %%a;%%i)>"db.csv"
)

You don't need another for. Just use that one line I gave you (adapt the searchstring and filemask to match your environment obviously) (no need to iterate over the files with a for, as findstr already does that)
